# Use multiple QR codes simultaneously on a screen for AR with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, qr-code

I am extremely new to Unity3D and AR generally. 
I am trying to build an app that will contain multiple QR codes 3-7 on a screen simultaneously and show a different animation/ image on each of them.

Is that possible?

I guess I cannot use Vuforia for this purpose, because I read on its page that “A maximum of 2 Object Targets can be tracked simultaneously.”

What about AR core? I read that "ARCore tracks up to 20 images simultaneously in the user's environment off-camera and on-camera, but does not track multiple instances of the same image."

Any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia Documentation says it can track up to 5 Image-Targets at a time:

> This is why the Vuforia SDK limits the maximum number of
>   simultaneously tracked image-based targets to 5, and provides an API
>   method that enables you to define a lower maximum for your app.

[here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Targets.html)

If you configure Vuforia to work with ARCore or ARKit under the hood (which it can and I would recommend, since the tracking is way more stable) you may be able to get even more, but that I don't know. Device performance will be the limiting factor for the number of Targets at that point. You can change the number of maximum targets in your vuforia settings on your ARCamera. If that doesn't work switching to ARCore without Vuforia sounds like an option, yes.

Hope that helps.